# Heroku error with Rails: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am uploading a slug to Heroku but I get the error in the topic title.  First, my config/environment/production.rb file

```
config/environment/production.rb
  <App Name>::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb


  #Devise Note:
  #config/environments/development.rb:

  #config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }

  #In production, :host should be set to the actual host of your application.


  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  # server smtp settings
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :openssl_verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE, 
    :address => "<address>",
    :port => 2525,
    :domain => "<domain>",
    :authentication => "plain",
    :user_name => ENV["smtp_un"],
    :password => ENV["smtp_pw"]
  }

  # Defaults to nil and saved in location specified by config.assets.prefix
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  # config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
end
```

There was a dangling `end` at the end of this file, but I removed it and repushed.  Heroku is throwing an error when it calls `rake assets:precompile` as it receives the push.  However, the error is thrown for `/tmp/build_<build_number>/config/environments/production.rb:91` not `config/environments/production.rb:91`.  I've looked in the `/tmp` folder but there is no folder with a build number listed on my development environment.  What is Heroku looking at and how can I fix this error?

---

Locally, I am using the following:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24 revision 45159) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]
$ rvm -v
rvm 1.25.25 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.16
```

However, Heroku is using ruby 2.0.0, see:

```
$ git push heroku master
...
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.5.2
       Ruby version change detected. Clearing bundler cache.
       Old: ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [x86_64-linux]
       New: ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [x86_64-linux]
```

I'm not sure if this matters

Comment: Can you post a link to git repo

Comment: Your comment led me to the correct answer.  I made my changes on `(no branch)` and kept pushing `master` to Heroku

Comment: Damn wanted that bounty! Glad you got it figured out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made my changes on `(no branch)` and kept pushing `master` to Heroku.  Switching to master and changing `config/environments/production.rb` fixed the issue.